# Can a neutron star/quark star have a photon sphere?

Tags: photons, orbital-motion, neutron-stars

Can a neutron star/quark star have a photon sphere?
A photon sphere has a radius equal to 1.5 times the Schwarzschild radius. Is it possible for a neutron star to have on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. This is discussed in the article "Properties of ultracompact neutron stars" by Nemiroff, R. J., Becker, P. A., & Wood, K. S. (http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1993ApJ...406..590N)

Comment: Please do not rely on links surviving indefintely.  We want to avoid [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) making answers useless.  Instead make a very brief summary of the key points/reasons that the article describes.  This way answers are standalone.  On Physics SE we generally give a link to the *abstract* page rather than the article/document itself.